# Can I hold a List<> of Object Types of the same descendant?

Tags: c#, oop, list, inheritance

I need to hold a list of **object types** that are allowed to do certain actions.

Example `Animal` has 3 descendants `Tiger`, `Human`, `Hippo`

I want to allow only `Tiger`s and `Hippo`s to be held in zoo cages? I need a list of animal types.

I would love something better than `List<Type>`

*This is just a simplified example. I don't like animals in cages..*

**edit**

Since it's not clear. I want to hold object types in the list and not actual objects.

Example:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(typeof(Hippo));
types.Add(typeof(Tiger));
```

This has the limit that a programmer can do `types.Add(typeof(Human))` and this is what I wan't to dissallow.

**edit2**

Just to clarify my question. I want to be able to dynamically `Register` allowed types and not having consequent `if`s as some answers bellow.

Comment: `I want to allow only Tigers and Hippos to be held in zoo cages` This is too allegorical for me. Can you please give a code example of what you want to do?

Comment: I guess you could have ZooAnimal descendant of Animal and inherit only Tiger and Hippo from it and then have List<ZooAnimal>?

Comment: What's wrong with `List<Type>`?

Comment: In the List<Type> any Type is allowed. I want to limit that

Comment: @Veli I do not want object instances, but object **Types** in the list

Comment: @odyodyodys If you don't want to hold instances and you have constrained the types to only two types, why do you need a list of them? `typeof(Tiger)` and `typeof(Hippo)` in line in code should suffice. You cannot constrain `Type` any further to a subset of what type's are valid, without implementing a custom list that guards what is added.

Comment: Why dont you try creating another class named ZooAnimals : Animals and Tiger : ZooAnimals. This way you could use List<ZooAnimals> as this would overcome your difficulty of using List<Type>. Please let me know if you find this useful.

Comment: What's the point to keep a list of only maximum of two types?

Answer (score 4):

**If you want a list of only certain types:**

There isn't anything in generics that can support what you are asking for, so simply create a custom type that allows you to store `Type` types and have code at runtime for guarding against invalid entries:

```
public class CagedTypes 
{
    private readonly List<Type> _types;

    public void Add(Type t)
    {
        if (t == typeof(Hippo) || t == typeof(Tiger))
            _types.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Although I can't see why you might need this.

**Alternative if you want a list of only certain types:**

Do the same as above, but include the interface below and change the add check to something like:

```
public void Add(Type t)
{
    if (t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICanBeHeldInZooCage)))
        _types.Add(t);
}
```

You could also use attributes, as you can query a type for any attributes using the `GetAttributes` method.

**If you wish to only have certain instances in a list:**

Create a marker interface:

```
public interface ICanBeHeldInZooCage
```

That `Tiger` and `Hippo` implement (doesn't have to do anything), then you can have:

```
var cagedAnimals = new List<ICanBeHeldInZooCage>();
```

Comment: Exactly that multiple `if` part is what I want to avoid. I've edited the question to include the fact that I want to register allowed types in runtime

Comment: @odyodyodys I've amended my answer with another option. It uses the convention that an interface exists on the allowed types.

Comment: +1 for all the additional options, personally I prefer to store the types in an interface and use that interface to hold the types in a list.

Answer (score 4):

Approach1 - via interfaces:

```
public interface ICageable
{ }

public abstract class Animal
{}

public class Hippo : Animal, ICageable
{}

public class Human : Animal, ICageable
{}

public IEnumerable<Type> GetCageableAnimals()
{
    return  GetAssemblyTypes(assembly:typeof(Animal).Assembly)
        .Where(type=>IsDerivedFrom(type, typeof(Animal)))
        .Where(type=>ImplementsInterface(type,typeof(ICageable)));
}
```

Approach 2 - via attribute:

```
public class InCageAttribute : Attribute
{ }

public abstract class Animal
{}

[InCage]
public class Hippo : Animal
{}

public class Human : Animal
{}

public IEnumerable<Type> GetCageableAnimals()
{
    return  GetAssemblyTypes(assembly:typeof(Animal).Assembly)
        .Where(type=>IsDerivedFrom(type, typeof(Animal)))
        .Where(type=>MarkedByAttribute(type,typeof(InCageAttribute)));
}
```

**UPDATE**

**IMPORTANT**

Both these approaches provide only runtime check. having compilation check  implementation would be better, but don't know for know how to achieve that.

**UPDATE2**
For dynamic registration:

```
public class CageRegistry
{
    private List<Type> _allowedTypes = new List<Type>();
    public IEnumerable<Type> AllowedTypes{get{return _allowedTypes;}}

    public bool TryAdd(Type type)
    {
        if(ImplementsInterface(type, typeof(ICageable)))// for approach with attributes code is pretty similar
        {
            _allowedTypes.Add(type);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**PS2**
Sorry for not implemented methods like `MarkedByAttribute`, `IsDerivedFrom` and `ImplementsInterface` - I just don't have visual studio on current machine yet and don't remember api exactly.

Comment: I've edited my question to include that I want to dynamically register allowed types and not at compile type. Although I found your answers intereting

Comment: Yeah, I've read your update, that's why I've written that code - thought it's dynamic enough :) you can invoke it dynamically, whatever it means :) Speaking seriously, what do you mean by "dynamic registration of allowed types" ?

Answer (score 3):

How about an Interface?

```
public interface ICageable {}

public abstract class Animal {}

public class Hippo : Animal, ICageable {}

public class Tiger : Animal, ICageable {}

public class Human : Animal, ICageable {}

public class Ape : Animal {}

....
List<ICageable> ZooAnimals = new List<ICageable>{hippo, tiger, human};
```

(writing from a Planet of the Apes perspective)

and if you need the types themselves in a list, well types are instances of the `Type` type, so whatever you create it will be a collection of types. You could encapsulate is like this:

```
public class CageableTypesCollection : 
{
    private List<Type> _cageableTypes;

    public CageableTypesCollection()
    {
       _cageableTypes = new List<Type>();
    }

    public RegisterType(Type t)
    {
       if (!typeof(ICageable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
          throw new ArgumentException("wrong type of type");
       _cageableTypes.Add(t);
    }

    public UnregisterType(Type t)
    {
       ....
    }

    .....

}
```

Comment: I want to hold object `Type`s and not object instances. This is clear in both the question title and body. I don't understand why this is answer has upvotes at all.

Comment: @odyodyodys: added the types thing, sorry, misread the question first, but left it as a preamble.

Comment: Thanks, that seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an interface to determine if an animal is a ZooAnimal

```
  public class Animal
  {
    public string Name;
  }
  public class Tiger : Animal, IZooAnimal
  {

  }
  public class Human : Animal
  {

  }
  public interface IZooAnimal
  {
    //Some zoo animal properties
  }
```

And then check if the animal is a Zoo Animal `if (a is IZooAnimal)` below is a zoo class which you could use.

```
  public class Zoo
  {
    public List<IZooAnimal> AnimalsInZoo = new List<IZooAnimal>();
    public void AddAnimal(IZooAnimal a)
    {
      AnimalsInZoo.Add(a);
    }
  }
```

EDIT:

Ok now to do this with types and constrain the types to a `ZooAnimal` I have made a generic zoo class which takes `T` where T is a ZooAnimal - you could have a list of ZooAnimals or a list of tigers in our case.

```
  public class Zoo<T> where T : IZooAnimal
  {
    public List<Type> AnimalTypes = new List<Type>();
    public void AddType(Type a)
    {
      if (typeof(T) == a)
        AnimalTypes.Add(a);
    }
  }
```

This will add `type` Tiger to the `AnimalsInZoo`. Hope this works for you.

```
  Zoo<IZooAnimal> cage = new Zoo<IZooAnimal>();
  cage.AddType(typeof(Tiger));
  cage.AddType(typeof(Human));
```

Comment: @AgentFire Thanks - too quick for my own good, why I wanted to pass an animal and cast it instead of only accepting an `IZooAnimal` in the constructor i'll never know!

Comment: @LukeHannerley I want to hold object types and not object instances

Comment: @odyodyodys So in a `List` you want to hold a `List<Type>`, you never want to hold instances?

Comment: Change `public class Zoo<T> where T : IZooAnimal` to `public class Zoo` and `if (typeof(T) == a)` to `if (a.IsAssignableFrom(IZooAnimal))`

Answer (score 1):

Human is *animal*, Tiger is *animal that should be in zoo*. So in your case I'd create one more base class for `Tiger` and `Hippo`.

```
public class AnimalInZoo : Animal {}
public class Tiger : AnimalInZoo {}
public class Hippo : AnimalInZoo {}
public class Human : Animal {}
```

You can create helper function `AddInZoo(AnimalInZoo obj)` to add in you `List<Type> m_Zoo`:

```
void AddInZoo(AnimalInZoo obj)
{
    m_Zoo.Add(obj.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract bool IsCagable { get; }
}
```

And let the nested classes to implement their behavior.

Later then, the some sort of `Zoo` class which is mostly presented in the answers in this topic, inside the method Add must do the check:

```
public sealed class ZooList : List<Animal> // I believe you need Animal, not Type
{
    // ... some implementations ...

    public override sealed void Add(Animal animal)
    {
        if (!animal.IsCagable)
            // Prevent from adding.
    }
}
```

Comment: As IsCageable is an instance variable, this could mean that some instances of a certain type (let's say humans) are cageable, and some not, so it would be moved from the type level (where the OP requires it) to the instance level.